# import data from excel to datagridview with datagridview has already columns in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

So I want to import data from excel to datagridview. Datagridview has already columns and when i try to import, the data in excel does not lined in the columns in datagridview instead it will create new columns to the right. How to solve this?

Here is the code:

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection
Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dts As DataSet
Dim excel As String
Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

     Try
        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "XLS files (*.xls, *.xlt)|*.xls;*.xlt|XLSX files (*.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xltx, *.xltm)|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xltx;*.xltm"
        If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excel & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
            DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
            conn.Close()

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns).

Comment: can you show me how to implement this to my code?

Comment: If you want to bind data to a grid that already has columns, you need to set the `DataPropertyName` property of each column so that it knows which property/column of the data source to bind to. If you set the `DataPropertyName` properties correctly, the value of `AutoGenerateColumns` is irrelevant, unless your data source has extra properties/columns that you don;t want displayed in the grid.

Comment: And before you ask, no I'm not going to show you what to do. It's a simple case of setting one property per column, which you would likely do in the designer if that's where you're adding the columns. Read the appropriate documentation first if you're not sure. VS has a Help menu for a reason.

Comment: Thank you for this dude. You have no idea how helpful you are

Comment: i encounter a problem, i cannot edit the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just write this Line in your Code and add Few columns first for testing this code :

```
 DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

this statement will not affect existing columns of datagridview and add new columns to datagridview.

Comment: 1) don't use bold in the answer statement, only to highlight specific keywords. 2) You need to tell how the line can be helpful to the situation

Comment: @NitinSingh Thank you for the help,  I am new to this site so i need to learn more about formatting.